# getting graphql error Cannot return null for non-nullable field Account.groups. How to resolve?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have a problem, when launching a query "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Account.groups".
I have graphql resolver:

```
@Resolver(of => Account)
export class AccountResolver {
    constructor(
        @Inject(AccountService) private accountService: AccountService,
    ) { }

    @Query(returns => [Account], {
        description: `To get all client's accounts`
    })
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
    async accounts(
        @Context('clientId') clientId: string,
    ): Promise<Account[]> {
        return await this.accountService.getAllAccounts(clientId);
    }
}
```

And model:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Account {

    @Field()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Field()
    @Column('text', {
        default: ''
    })
    firstName: string;

    @Field()
    @Column('text', {
        default: ''
    })
    lastName: string;

    @Field()
    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        default: ''
    })
    avatar: string;

    @Field()
    @Column('text', {
        unique: true,
    })
    username: string;

    @Column('text', { nullable: false })
    @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
    password: string;

    @Field()
    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 300,
        enum: Roles,
        nullable: false
    })
    role: Roles

    @Field()
    @Column('text', { nullable: false, unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Field()
    @Column({
        default: false
    })
    emailVerified: boolean;
    
    @Field()
    @Column('text', { nullable: true, default: ''})
    verificationLink: string;

    @OneToMany(() => KitTask, kitTask => kitTask.account)
    kitTasks: KitTask[];

    @OneToMany(() => Trace, trace => trace.account)
    traces: Trace[];


    @Field(type => Client)
    @ManyToOne(() => Client, client => client.accounts, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    client: Client;

    @Field(type => Group)
    @ManyToMany(() => Group, group => group.accounts)
    @JoinTable()
    groups: Group[];
    
}
```

I'm trying to launch query:

query accounts{
accounts{
id
firstName
lastName
avatar
username
role
email
emailVerified
client {
name
}
groups {
id
}
}

And getting the following error:
[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you implemented [Field Resolvers](https://typegraphql.com/docs/resolvers.html#field-resolvers) for both `client` and `groups`? If you run the query without `client` and `groups` it works?

Comment: it works, if I run it with clients, but not with groups

Comment: Do not automatically retrieve data from join tables, use Field Resolver(s). Since `groups` is a many to many relation, I think that TypeORM does not automatically select the data